# How do I escape an argument of a bash script in awk?

Tags: bash, awk, parameters, arguments, escaping

I have the following issue. I want to run a script with 2 parameters like:

`./Myscript.sh $1 $2`

`$1` is a number, nothing special but `$2`  It's actually a message that looks like this:

```
“My message`-12355, this is a message !56432-I am sure it`s a message-46583”.
```

This message was actually extracted with an awk from some log files. Myscript.sh executes a curl http post and uses the $1 and $2 as parameters for creating the json in curl command like

```
-d '{"number":"$1","message":"$2"}'
```

My question is how do I “escape” the argument $2 since the message contains special characters?

Thanks

I'm calling `Myscript.sh` from another script in a awk command using:

```
system(./Myscript.sh “$1” \”$2\”)
```

I was thinking to use backslashes to “escape” but this not seems to work. Any ideas or help would be great. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use `"` and not `“`.

```
system("./Myscript.sh \"" $1 "\" \"" $2 "\"")
```

Comment: I was actually using " but was a miss type from my phone :) anyway I ll try your suggestion in my script. Thanks a lot. I will come with a later feedback.

Answer (score 0):

you have exclamation mark (`"!"`) in your shell `$2` - I'd safely single-quote them if I were you ::

```
 sh: ./Myscript.sh: No such file or directory

 system() command :::

      './Myscript.sh' '1114111' 
                      'My message`-12355, this is a 
                          message !56432-I'\''m sure it`s a message-46583'

# gawk profile, created Mon Jan  9 05:37:09 2023
# Rule(s)

 1 ' {
 1      print "system() command :::\f\f\r\t",

               system_cmd = escSQ($1)  (_ = " ") 
                            escSQ($2)_ escSQ($3)
 1      system(system_cmd)
    }

 3  function escSQ(__,_) {

 3         _ = "\47"
 3      gsub(_,"&\\" (_)_,__)

 3      return (_)(__)_
    }'
```

ps : this approach is okay only if none of the command items have items that *need* to be interpreted by the shell, e.g. `~` (as prefix for script itself) or `$?` etc